# Economics of Health Textbook Recommendation

Tags: reference-request, health-economics, teaching

Was wondering if anyone who has taught a class on health economics could give some background on which textbook they used for their class and why.

It seems like "Healthy Economics" by Bhattacharya, Hyde and Tu or "The Economics of Health and Health Care" by Folland, Goodman and Stano are the two most popular texts, but I haven't read either. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The two main textbooks in any Health Economics class are: Michael F. Drummond - Methods for The Economic Evaluation of Health Care Programmes and Andrew Briggs - Decision Modelling for Health Economic Evaluation. These are must read books. Michael Drummond is a legend in the area of Health Economics. He is the author of two major textbooks and more than 600 scientific papers, has acted as a consultant to the World Health Organization and was Project Leader of a European Union Project on the Methodology of Economic Appraisal of Health Technology. He has also served on the Boards of Directors of the International Society of Technology Assessment in Health Care and the International Society for Pharmacoeconomics and Outcomes Research.